# Multi compartmental ODE's in chemical engineering

Tags: nomenclature, computational-chemistry, chemical-engineering

I am alien to the field of chemical engineering. And I am confused about equations, written by chemical engineers, including several variables belonging to **different compartments**.

Assume that,

- $[X]$ is in concentration units and belongs to the $V_X$ compartment.
- $[Y]$ is in concentration units and belongs to the $V_Y$ compartment.
- $X$ has a negative feedback on itself and $Y$ increases $X$.

I would write my equation as following,

$\frac{d [X]}{dt} \times V_X = [X]\times V_X - [Y] \times V_Y$.

I would write this way, because these should be amounts not concentrations (right?).

However the equations are,

$\frac{d [X]}{dt} = [X] - [Y]$.

I don't understand how concentrations can be used that way. I would be very happy if anyone could help me to solve this issue.

Thanx!

Comment: I can be written in 2 ways. Using intensive quantities (and their derivatives) like concentrations, or using extensive quantities like molar amounts, but then volumes must be used to express relations between both.

Comment: but both are accepted as correct in chemical engineering, I see. Thank you!